# How do I Install Unity 2D Extras on MacOS?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, terminal, homebrew, macos-catalina

There is a package from Unity

> https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/2d-extras

That lets you edit 2D Tilemaps more freely but is not integrated on the actual version. I'am trying to get it installed on my MacOS and recognized by Unity. I've installed HomeBrew to install git, up to there I think I'm good but now I need to set some sort of path to make Unity able to use it. I don't know how to do that and I don't have find much information about it. If someone could help me it would be really appreciated. I'am not used to work on the terminal so all this thing is really confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

The repo's `README.md` file mentions how to install the package. One of the ways (The simpler one) is to just download the package and put it in `YOUR_UNITY_PROJECT\Packages` directory.

The `README.md`:
https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/2d-extras/blob/master/README.md